# rails 3, find_by_sql, date_format, too few arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following find_by_sql and am getting a 'too few arguments' error. Any ideas to fix? Would like to just keep it as a find_by_sql

```
dates=find_by_sql(['select DATE(start_datetime) date_only,  DATE_FORMAT(start_datetime,\'\%b \%D\') as formatted_date from events where area_id=1 group by date_only'])
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double percentage symbols to escape a percentage inside of a finder:

```
dates = find_by_sql(['select DATE(start_datetime) date_only,  DATE_FORMAT(start_datetime,\'\%%b \%%D\') as formatted_date from events where area_id=1 group by date_only'])
```